# Doctrine ORM: composite and foreign keys as primary key

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I am trying to get composite and foreign keys as primary keys working in Doctrine ORM. I know what I'm trying to do is possible because it is described here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#composite-and-foreign-keys-as-primary-key. This is exactly my use-case: I have some products, an order and an order item.

However, doctrine orm is unable to map this relation unto the database. The current problem is that only one of the annotated `\Id` primary keys is reflected on the mysql database. So $producto is translated unto the database correctly as `producto_id` and is both a primary key and a foreign key. However, the `$orden` property which is annotated in the same way doesn't appear whatsoever on my database.

[image]

This seems odd because when I was first testing this feature I tried only with one of the two properties and it worked fine, however, when both properties are annotated only one seems to be parsed by the metadata parser. Furthermore, I tried to revert my project to a usable state by forgetting about the foreign keys and just have a composite primary key (like I had it before), but now the parser doesn't seem to even recognize the primary key. For example, for:

```
class ProductoOrden
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $idOrden;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $idProducto;
```

I get:

```
bash-3.2$ php bin/console make:migration

In MappingException.php line 52:
                                                                                                
  No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "App\Entity\ProductoOrden". Every Entity must  
   have an identifier/primary key.
```

So I'm unable to set it up properly or to revert it to the previous state (which is the strangest of all).

I'm about to restart my whole project from scratch, because I cannot make sense of how the metadata parsing works. I am worried I have screwed up the process because I have manually erased the files at 'src\Migrations' because of similar issues before and `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:version --delete --all` didn't seem to work or I haven't understood the proper use of it.

In conclusion: ¿Could anyone assert if what I am trying to do with ProducoOrden is possible (maybe I'm not understanding the documentation example)? Is there any way to completely wipe out previous cache about the annotations/ schema metadata?

I've looked unto the `orm:schema-tool` but I don't really get how to configure it properly or why I have to configure it at all of I already have the `bin/console` tool on my project.

I will show all three involved classes for completeness sake, but the main problem is within ProductoOrden (Order-items).

```
<?php

//Products
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ProductosRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductosRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity("idProducto", message=" {producto {{ value }}}: llave primaria violada ")
*/
class Productos
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;    

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nombreProducto;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $descripcionProducto;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $urlImagen;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $puntosProducto;

    public function getIdProducto(): ?int
    {
        return $this->idProducto;
    }

    public function getCodProducto(): ?int
    {
      return $this->idProducto;
    }

    public function setIdProducto(int $codProducto): self
    {
        $this->idProducto = $codProducto;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNombreProducto(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nombreProducto;
    }

    public function setNombreProducto(string $nombreProducto): self
    {
        $this->nombreProducto = $nombreProducto;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescripcionProducto(): ?string
    {
        return $this->descripcionProducto;
    }

    public function setDescripcionProducto(string $descripcionProducto): self
    {
        $this->descripcionProducto = $descripcionProducto;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUrlImagen(): ?string
    {
        return $this->urlImagen;
    }

    public function setUrlImagen(string $urlImagen): self
    {
        $this->urlImagen = $urlImagen;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPuntosProducto(): ?int
    {
        return $this->puntosProducto;
    }

    public function setPuntosProducto(int $puntosProducto): self
    {
        $this->puntosProducto = $puntosProducto;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString(){
      $str = '{producto:'.$this->getIdProducto().', nombre: '.$this->getNombreProducto().'}';
      return $str;
    }
}
```

```
<?php
\\Orders
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\OrdenesRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=OrdenesRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity("idOrden", message="{orden {{ value }}}: llave primaria violada")
 */
class Ordenes
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $totalOrden;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $estado;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ProductoOrden::class, mappedBy="orden", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $productosOrden;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->productosOrden = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getIdOrden(): ?int
    {
        return $this->idOrden;
    }

    public function setIdOrden(int $idOrden): self
    {
        $this->idOrden = $idOrden;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTotalOrden(): ?int
    {
        return $this->totalOrden;
    }

    public function setTotalOrden(int $totalOrden): self
    {
        $this->totalOrden = $totalOrden;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEstado(): ?string
    {
        return $this->estado;
    }

    public function setEstado(string $estado): self
    {
        $this->estado = $estado;

        return $this;
    }
    public function __toString(){
      $str = '{orden:'.$this->getIdOrden().'}';
      return $str;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|ProductoOrden[]
     */
    public function getProductosOrden(): Collection
    {
        return $this->productosOrden;
    }

    public function addProductosOrden(ProductoOrden $productosOrden): self
    {
        if (!$this->productosOrden->contains($productosOrden)) {
            $this->productosOrden[] = $productosOrden;
            $productosOrden->setOrden($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProductosOrden(ProductoOrden $productosOrden): self
    {
        if ($this->productosOrden->contains($productosOrden)) {
            $this->productosOrden->removeElement($productosOrden);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($productosOrden->getOrden() === $this) {
                $productosOrden->setOrden(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
<?php
\\Order-items
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ProductoOrdenRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductoOrdenRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"idOrden","idProducto"}, message="{prod. orden {{ value }}}: llave primaria violada")
 */
class ProductoOrden
{
    /*
     *  @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Ordenes::class, inversedBy="productosOrden")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $orden;

      /**
       * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Productos::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $producto;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $puntos;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $cantidad;



    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->idOrden;
    }
   public function setIdOrden(int $idOrden): self
   {
    $this ->idOrden = $idOrden;

    return $this;

   }
    public function getIdProducto(): ?int
    {
        return $this->idProducto;
    }

    public function setIdProducto(int $idProducto): self
    {
        $this->idProducto = $idProducto;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPuntos(): ?int
    {
        return $this->puntos;
    }

    public function setPuntos(int $puntos): self
    {
        $this->puntos = $puntos;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCantidad(): ?int
    {
        return $this->cantidad;
    }

    public function setCantidad(int $cantidad): self
    {
        $this->cantidad = $cantidad;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString(){

      $str = '{productoOrden:'.$this->getId().', '.$this->getIdProducto().'}';
      return $str;
    }

    public function getOrden(): ?Ordenes
    {
        return $this->orden;
    }

    public function setOrden(?Ordenes $orden): self
    {
        $this->orden = $orden;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

For the shown classes, the migration it generates is

```
final class Version20200814210929 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function getDescription() : string
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE producto_orden ADD puntos INT NOT NULL');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE producto_orden DROP puntos');
    }
}
```

As you can see, small changes like changing the type of a property work; but it doesn't seem to take on the id() and the association annotations.

Many thanks

Comment: Do not rely on the GUI icons. Take a look at your doctrine migration code and export your table in order to look at the generated SQL. Is the composite key declared ?

Comment: @rugolinifr. No it isn't, the  `make:migration` script doesn't seem to read the 'entity' folder classes well.  I suspect something went wrong with the metadata but im unfamiliar as of how to do a complete reset of migrations and metadata. I tried deleting everything on `\Migrations`,  but im still stuck.

What do you mean by 'export' my table. Im only aware of the migrations code generated by `make:migration' and the actual execution of the migration in 'migrations:migrate'. Maybe you are talking of something else I don't know about?
 Thanks